# To become a BGI, what are the minimal requirements from the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-instructor

To become a Basic Ground Instructor (BGI), what are the minimal requirements from the FAA?

I am especially interested in understanding the minimal certifications (PPL/CPL) that are needed to obtain the BGI.

Comment: Related? [What is the step-by-step process to become a ground instructor in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29445/1696)

Comment: What is BGI? I've been flying since 1994, never saw that acronym.

Comment: @CrossRoads - "Basic Ground Instructor"

Comment: Ah - I skipped Ground instruction, just studied on my own and anything I couldn't figure out for the Knowledge exam (both Private and Instrument) I worked out with my flight instructor.  Ground school with a bunch of non-engineers had no appeal to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is found in [FAR 61.213](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/1BBF0F32D15A044B8625768F005C3BFB?OpenDocument)

For your convenience I've copied and pasted the entire thing here, but you should reference the official link as regulations change from time to time. Highlighting is mine.

*Note that no pilot's certificate of any kind is necessary.*

> (a) To be eligible for a ground instructor certificate or rating a
>   person must:
>
> (1) Be at least **18 years of age**;
>
> (2) Be able to **read,
>   write, speak, and understand the English language**. If the applicant is
>   unable to meet one of these requirements due to medical reasons, then
>   the Administrator may place such operating limitations on that
>   applicant's ground instructor certificate as are necessary;
>
> (3) Except
>   as provided in paragraph (b) of this section, **pass a knowledge test** on
>   the fundamentals of instructing to include-- (i) The learning process;
>   (ii) Elements of effective teaching; (iii) Student evaluation and
>   testing; (iv) Course development; (v) Lesson planning; and (vi)
>   Classroom training techniques.
>
> (4) **Pass a knowledge test** on the
>   aeronautical knowledge areas in-- [(i) For a basic ground instructor
>   rating, Secs. 61.97, 61.105, and 61.309; (ii) For an advanced ground
>   instructor rating, Secs. 61.97, 61.105, 61.125, 61.155, and 61.309;
>   and] (iii) For an instrument ground instructor rating, Sec. 61.65. (b)
>
> The knowledge test specified in paragraph (a)(3) of this section is
>   not required if the applicant:
>
> (1) Holds a ground instructor
>   certificate or flight instructor certificate issued under this part;
>
> (2) Holds a teacher's certificate issued by a State, county, city, or municipality that authorizes the person to teach at an
>   educational level of the 7th grade or higher; or
>
> (3) Is employed as a teacher at an accredited college or university.

Comment: Because the OP specifically asked about it, you might like to mention that there's no requirement to hold a pilot's certificate of any kind

Comment: @Pondlife Good call!