# What written tests are required to become a ground instructor?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-instructor

What are the written tests required to become a ground instructor? Do I have to take the FOI, BGI and IGI? Or just the FOI and IGI tests?

I got confused if I should take the whole three tests - FOI, BGI, IGI - or if just the two IGI and FOI tests are enough?

Comment: The AGI covers all of the BGI info, so you want to take it instead. IGI covers instrument only. FOI is required for any ground or flying instructor unless you are an active teacher at a school or college.

Answer (score 1):

[The FAA offers some nice guidance here](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8700.1%20GA%20Ops%20Insp%20Handbk/Volume%202/2_159_00.htm)

[image]

[You may also want to check out my answer (a very close to dupe) here.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29445/what-is-the-step-by-step-process-to-become-a-ground-instructor-in-the-us)

Comment: Am I reading this table wrong? I t looks like you can get an AGI just by taking the BGI and IGI, without either the AGI or FOI?